# A7 API SDK for controlling shooting interval remotely - Timelapse

Tags: camera, sony

I am interested on writing an app that can turn the Sony A7 into a precise timelapse camera with less than a second shooting interval.
Can I use the Sony SDK API for that?
How, and how fast can I control the shutter of the camera?
Thanks
Vangelis

Answer (score 1):

This is what the documentation says about the shooting speed concerning the latest version of the API:

Continuous shooting speed ("10fps 1sec")

Please let me know if you need more detail. I am sure you already have this, but here is the link to the home page for camera development:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/